# access azure mobile from windows 7 net4.0?

Tags: azure

we are using Azure Mobile Service to store some data from Android, iOS and WP8 clients. This works fine.

Is there any way to access this data with .Net 4.0 from Windows 7 ? 
The Azure Mobile SDK requires Net 4.5 but we still need to target 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best (and at the same time the hardest) way would be to use the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710108.aspx) directly. The SDKs are just a wrapper for this API.